# Why does Python Tutor draw strings and integers in a list without a pointer although everything in python is a reference?

Tags: python

I read that "everything is a reference in python".

Though, when I run in Python Tutor the following code:

```
lst = [1,[1]]
```

`lst[1]` is drawn as an arrow pointing to a list while `lst[0]` is just the number `1`.

I also understand that what makes the difference is that `lst[0]` is immutable and `lst[1]` is mutable. I still don't get how to explain the drawing in Python Tutor, or any other explanation.

The drawing in Python Tutor looks as if the number itself is saved in `lst[0]` and not a reference, but I guess this is wrong because "everything in python is a reference".

How can we explain the drawing otherwise? Is the drawing in Python Tutor misleading and there is actually an address stored in `lst[0]`?

Comment: `lst[0]` is a reference to an integer (`1`), and `lst[1]` is a reference to another list. That other list contains a reference to the integer `1` as well. This has nothing to do with mutability.

Comment: What might confuse you is that https://pythontutor.com doesn't bother to draw the integer `1` as a separate object with arrows from the lists to it.

Comment: I really hate the "everything is a reference in python" quote because it's so devoid of clarifying details and is so easily mistaken with other concepts. "Everything is an object in python" is similarly too vague but I feel it's not as confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're right: there is an address stored in `lst[0]`, the address of a Python object of type `int`, representing the integer 1.

That's literally true in CPython (the "standard" C implementation of Python), but other implementations may use other means.

By convention, diagrams usually show arrows only for "container" objects, which are objects that contain other objects (lists, sets, tuples, dicts, ...). "Scalar" types, which do not contain other objects (ints, floats, bools, ...), are typically shown by displaying a human-readable string naming the value the object represents. Nevertheless, container objects never contain scalar objects *directly* - they store instead pointers to the Python objects implementing the scalar objects.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that a container (not sure if there's a strict definition but let's say indexable and iterable) can hold values that are NOT pointers to Python objects. However, they are not holding Python objects either. An `int64` NumPy array directly stores 64-bit integer values, just like some other languages store primitive values in arrays. However, Python has no primitive types, so when you index a NumPy array, a new scalar object is created to hold the integer value.

Comment: Yes, and essentially the same is true of a built-in Python `array.array`.